# RPG Pygame while loop reset in class

Tags: python, class, while-loop, pygame

Right now I am having a problem where a class' values are being reset I am not sure where. can anyone help? Here is the code

```
while True:
   #some code#
   Hub().paint(gameDisplay)
```

The Hub/paint function is shown below

```
def paint(self, screen):
    if self.gimseen == 0 and self.pressed == 0:
        screen.blit(image1, (self.x, self.y))
        self.pressed = (pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0])
        if self.pressed == 1:
            self.gimseen += 1
```

Comment: Every time you invoke `Hub().paint(gameDisplay)`, you're creating a new instance  of  `Hub` with default instance variables. I think that's where your problem lies.

Comment: How would I fix this and still call the function. thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "class' values are being reset" you mean you set the values of `self.gimseen`, `self.pressed`, etc. on an instance of `Hub` and notice that these values all seem to be reset when you invoke `Hub().paint(gameDisplay)`, the reason is that you're creating a new instance of `Hub` each time that line is invoked.

To correct this, you'd most likely want to create a single instance of `Hub` before the while loop, update it in the body of the while loop and then call `paint` on that instance:

```
hub = Hub()
while True:
   #some code#
   hub.paint(gameDisplay)
```

Comment: Thanks and that does help however in some code I call a function that i also use to get the value of self.pressed is there any other way I could do this? thanks

Comment: @ChrisHowe I'm not sure what you mean.